# Is manipulating natural numbers in this fashion valid?

Tags: logic

Say I have a natural number $ a \in \mathbb N$

It follows then that $ 7 \mid 7a $ and $ 7a = 7a $

And then moving on:

$ 49a^2 - 35 = 49a^2 - 35 $

$ 7(7a^2 - 5) = 7(7a^2 - 5) $

$ 7a^2 - 5 = 7 (\frac{7a^2 - 5}{7}) $

Would it make sense to say that $ \exists r \in \mathbb N, r = \frac{7a^2 - 5}{7} $ such that $ 7a^2 - 5 = 7 r $ ? Would it make sense to claim $r$ as being a natural number since its constituents are all natural?

In case r isn't a natural number, can anybody give me a situation where I can always be certain that the derived value is natural?

Sorry if this question insults the intelligence of the general math.stackexchange populace. I'm suffering a bit of brain fog right now.

Comment: Just take $a=1$ and you see this isn't true ($r=2/7$). The natural numbers are closed under addition and multiplication, but NOT division, which is where this argument falls apart.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a natrual number $r$ with $7r=b$ if and only if $b$ is a natural number with $7|b$. (Note that $7|b$ is defined as: There exists an integer $r$ such that $b=7r$).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just claim that r is a natural number based on the fact that its constituents are all natural, like anything in maths you have to prove that r is natural and just stating that it is because its constituents are all natural will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

The natural numbers are closed under multiplication, but there is not a multiplicative inverse. They do not form a group.

As such, $7^{-1}$ is not in the natural numbers, so the step where you (implicitly) say

$$7^{-1}\cdot 7(7a^2-5) = 7^{-1} \cdot 7(7a^2-5) \implies 7a^2-5 = 7\left(\frac{7a^2-5}{7}\right)$$

does not preserve the desired property.

For example, if $a=4$, then your first identity holds, but $7(4)^2-5 = 107$ is not divisible by 7.

Comment: So anytime I divide, any claim I made about the divisor or the dividend will not automatically transfer over to the result right?

Comment: It depends on the set you're working in. The property you claim in your first step ($7 | 7a$) is actually a property of multiplicative closure of the natural numbers. We read it as "seven divides seven times a", but what it really means in this context is that "seven times a is a multiple of seven." In this sense, division **does not generally exist** in this framework of natural numbers. There is no such division operation that is closed in this set.

Comment: There are, however, algebraic structures where division (except by zero) does make sense. A multiplicative group necessarily contains an inverse element $a^{-1}$ for each element $a$ such that $a^{-1} a = 1$. You can think of this as "division", in a sense, but really it's multiplication by an inverse.
$$ {} $$
So to answer your question, when you divide, the properties no longer carry over, because you're using rules for an algebraic structure that does not presume those properties. It's like moving to Canada and trying to apply US law. People still speak English, but the laws are different.

Comment: boom! makes sense. nice analogy +1